# Passing MPI_Comm from Fortran to C/C++ causes segmentation fault

Tags: c++, fortran, mpi, interop

I am trying to pass MPI communicator from Fortran to C/C++. I am not sure what kind of handle to pass: `type(MPI_Comm)`, `MPI_Fint`, or just integer. I tried several combinations of mentioned options but either I could not compile or got segmentation fault. The following codes produce the error message:

> Program received signal SIGSEGV: Segmentation fault - invalid memory
>   reference.

**Interface**

```
module Tailor_module

use mpi
use, intrinsic :: ISO_C_Binding, only: C_int, C_double, C_char, c_associated
use, intrinsic :: ISO_C_Binding, only: c_ptr, C_NULL_ptr

implicit none
private

interface

    function Tailor__getobject(comm) result(optr) bind(C, name="Tailor__getobject")
        import c_ptr
        implicit none
        integer, intent(in), value :: comm
        type(c_ptr) :: optr
    end function Tailor__getobject

end interface

type(c_ptr), save :: obj = c_null_ptr

public :: Create

CONTAINS

    subroutine Create(com)
        integer, intent(in) :: com
        obj = Tailor__getobject(comm=com)
        return
    end subroutine Create

end module Tailor_module
```

**Fortran driver**

```
program main

use mpi
use Tailor_module, only : Create
IMPLICIT NONE

integer error

call MPI_Init(error)
call Create(MPI_COMM_WORLD);
call MPI_Finalize (error)

end
```

**C++**

```
typedef void * OpaqueObject;

extern "C"
{
    OpaqueObject Tailor__getobject(MPI_Fint *f_handle);
}

OpaqueObject Tailor__getobject(MPI_Fint *f_handle)
{
    MPI_Comm comm;
    comm = MPI_Comm_f2c(*f_handle); 
    OpaqueObject s;
    return s;
}
```

Comment: Are you using MPICH or Open MPI (derivative) ?

Comment: I am using Open MPI

Comment: Are you sure about the `value` modifier ?

Comment: No. In fact I am not familiar with fortran. I am trying to make fortran interface to my c++ code.

Comment: I’d first try to remove that. If it does not help, can you show a stacktrace?

Comment: Removing `value` keyword got rid of the segmentation fault.